# Determine if this lottery system is profitable

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations, lotteries

I have a problem where I'm supposed to determine if a lottery system is profitable.  I solved the problem and found it to be profitable, but I am not 100% sure about all of my calculations.  Below is the rules of the game, and my calculations.

> There is a total of $30$ numbers to draw from and $6$ will be drawn (order does not matter).  There's also $3$ colored balls and all three will be drawn (order does matter).  Each ticket sold is unique, and every ticket is sold.  Tickets cost $\$1$.  The jackpot does not play a role in the payout cost.  Assume the jackpot is $\$0$.
>
> - Any ticket with $4$ matching numbers gets $\$10$.
> - Any ticket with $4$ matching numbers and the matching color sequence gets $\$50$.
> - Any ticket with $5$ matching numbers gets $\$1,000$.
> - Any ticket with $5$ matching numbers and the matching color sequence gets $\$5,000$.
> - Any ticket with $6$ matching numbers gets $\$100,000$.
> - Any ticket with $6$ matching numbers and the matching color sequence gets the jackpot.

First step was to find the total possible tickets sold.  The problem states that every ticket is sold, and every ticket is unique, so:

Combinations of numbers is $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 30 \\ 6 \\ \end{array}} \right)$ which is $593775$.

For color balls, order matters, so it's $3!$ which is 6.  So, the total possible number of tickets is $3!\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 30 \\ 6 \\ \end{array}} \right)$ which is $3562650$ meaning the lottery will bring in a total of \$3,562,650.00.

Now determine the money that must be paid out.  Since every ticket is sold, every possible winning ticket must be added to the total payout.  These are the calculations I'm not entirely sure about.

4 number winners:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics), the formula to find the particular number of winning tickets with 4 correct numbers is:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 6 \\ 4 \\ \end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 24 \\ 2 \\ \end{array}} \right)$$

The result is 4140, however 6 of these also have the correct color combination, so the total of \$10 winning tickets is 4134, costing \$41,340.  The remaining 6 tickets with correct color combinations will cost \$300.

5 number winners:

The formula for this case would be:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 6 \\ 5 \\ \end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c} 24 \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right)$$

The result is 144, but again 6 of these have a correct color combination so the total number of \$1,000 tickets is 138 costing \$138,000 and the reaming 6 tickets will cost \$30,000.

Finally, due to the nature of combinations there can only be one ticket with all 6 numbers, however plugging into the formula before also results in 1.  The payout for this ticket is \$100,000.  This is the part that's confusing me though and makes me think I did the other parts wrong.  If every ticket is sold and every ticket is unique, doesn't that mean there must be a jackpot winning ticket?  The math shows that there can only be one ticket with all 6 numbers, but that doesn't guarantee that it will have the correct color combination.  So, someone can win but not win the jackpot, but the question originally states that every ticket is sold...Are there multiple tickets with correct numbers?

Anyways, you get the total payout by adding the above payouts which comes to \$309,640 which is far less than the total income of \$3,562,650 so the lottery is profitable.

If anyone spots an error I'd appreciate it as I am not 100% sure I did this correctly.  There might also be a better way to calculate it.

Comment: I just realized that you can avoid the whole "multiply by total number combinations" because in the first part we divide by that same number.  So the formula for finding the total number of winning combinations of a particular set of numbers is just the numerator portion of those combination fractions.

Comment: To start, you need to define the rules more clearly. Apparently, from your work each ticket has 6 numbers (none repeated) and a color sequence. How much is the jackpot? Please edit for clarity, incorporating your comment into the edit. Also, please consider that the an outcome for the jackpot prize meets the conditions for all the others, and there are many other cases of such inclusion. I cannot figure out whether/how you have avoided double counting.

Comment: Yes thanks I forgot to include that bit, and also the jackpot does not matter.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the jackpot prize meets the conditions for all the others.  The winning condition is that all 6 numbers have to be correct and according to my calculations, there is only 1 ticket that will have all 6 correct numbers (assuming I did the math right, which was the reason I posted).  Lastly, what do you mean when you say how I have avoided double counting?

Comment: If items are not mutually exclusive, you can't add their counts to get the total count.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the tickets are unique make them mutually exclusive?

Comment: The part that I'm really not sure about is the number of tickets with the correct color combination.  Is it just 6 out of the total possible numbers, or is it the number divided by 6?  e.g. for the 4 correct number bracket, is it just 6 or is it actually 24 possible tickets with the correct numbers and color sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of $4140$ ways to choose exactly four correct numbers is fine, but you will then sell $6 \cdot 4140$ tickets with four correct numbers.  $4140$ will have the correct order of balls and $5 \cdot 4140=20700$ will not.  You have a similar problem with five and six correct numbers.

Comment: I see, that makes sense and that's the part that was confusing me.  Thank you very much!